# Flink: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DeserializationSchemaFactory' in the classpath

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using flink's table api, I receive data from kafka, then register it as 
a table, then I use sql statement to process, and finally convert the result 
back to a stream, write to a directory, the code looks like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 

    val sEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment 
    sEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime) 

    val tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(sEnv) 

   tEnv.connect( 
      new Kafka() 
        .version("0.11") 
        .topic("user") 
        .startFromEarliest() 
        .property("zookeeper.connect", "") 
        .property("bootstrap.servers", "") 
    ) 
      .withFormat( 
        new Json() 
          .failOnMissingField(false) 
          .deriveSchema()   //使用表的 schema 
      ) 
      .withSchema( 
        new Schema() 
          .field("username_skey", Types.STRING) 
      ) 
      .inAppendMode() 
      .registerTableSource("user") 
     val userTest: Table = tEnv.sqlQuery( 
      """ 
       select ** form ** join **"".stripMargin) 
    val endStream = tEnv.toRetractStream[Row](userTest) 
    endStream.writeAsText("/tmp/sqlres",WriteMode.OVERWRITE) 
    sEnv.execute("Test_New_Sign_Student") 
 }
```

I was successful in the local test, but when I submit the following command 
in the cluster, I get the following error:

=======================================================

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method 
caused an error. 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:546) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:426) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:804) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:280) 
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:215) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1044) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) 
        at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120) 
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could 
not find a suitable table factory for 
'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DeserializationSchemaFactory' in 
the classpath. 

Reason: No factory implements 
'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DeserializationSchemaFactory'. 

The following properties are requested: 
connector.properties.0.key=zookeeper.connect 
.... 
schema.9.name=roles 
schema.9.type=VARCHAR 
update-mode=append 

The following factories have been considered: 
org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvBatchTableSourceFactory 
org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvAppendTableSourceFactory 
org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvBatchTableSinkFactory 
org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvAppendTableSinkFactory 
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.Kafka011TableSourceSinkFactory 


        at 
org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService$.filterByFactoryClass(TableFactoryService.scala:176) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService$.findInternal(TableFactoryService.scala:125) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService$.find(TableFactoryService.scala:100) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.find(TableFactoryService.scala) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaTableSourceSinkFactoryBase.getDeserializationSchema(KafkaTableSourceSinkFactoryBase.java:259) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaTableSourceSinkFactoryBase.createStreamTableSource(KafkaTableSourceSinkFactoryBase.java:144) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryUtil$.findAndCreateTableSource(TableFactoryUtil.scala:50) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.ConnectTableDescriptor.registerTableSource(ConnectTableDescriptor.scala:44) 
        at 
org.clay.test.Test_New_Sign_Student$.main(Test_New_Sign_Student.scala:64) 
        at 
org.clay.test.Test_New_Sign_Student.main(Test_New_Sign_Student.scala) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
        at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
        at 
org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
```

===================================

Can someone tell me what caused this?  I am very confused about this........

Answer (score 9):

if you are using maven-shade-plugin, make sure SPI transformer is placed.

Flink uses java Service Provider to discover Source/Sink connector. 
Without this transformer, you will 100% encoutner "org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could 
not find a suitable table factory", which happened on me.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/connect.html#update-mode
flink officially points out this, search "SPI" on this page

```
<transformers>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
</transformers>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the JAR dependencies of the connectors (Kafka) and formats (JSON) that you are using to the classpath of your program, i.e., either build a fat JAR that includes them or provide them to the classpath of the Flink cluster by copying them in the `./lib` folder.

Check the [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/table/connect.html#dependencies) for links to download the respective dependencies.

Comment: I hava add flink-json and flink-flink-connector-kafka dependence to the pom file, but still have the question,

Comment: Adding the dependencies to the pom file is not sufficient. You need to make sure that these dependencies are added to the resulting (fat) jar and that you have the right entries in `META_INF/services` to make the factories accessible.

Comment: @FabianHueske hi fabian,I have the same issue, please have a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961025/flink-org-apache-flink-table-api-nomatchingtablefactoryexception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the met the same problem, just add parameters --connector.type kafka when you run your application will solve this. see [enter link description here](https://snailgary.org/fb4e9417eb88ee2788c49aaa2f00b6b5)